# How do i pass the fixed value with the input value into an array list using the constructor?

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

I'm trying to pass two values for an object to be passed into an ArrayList from a constructor, I'm stuck trying to figure out how to pass the rate value which has a fixed value in the constructor which another class is also inheriting from. The obj requires an int, double (int is via input).

```
public static HotelRoom roomNormal()
    {
        int room1to299;
        double rate;
        HotelRoom obj = null;

        room1to299 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter room number"));
        rate = obj.getRate();
        obj = new HotelRoom(room1to299, rate);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"--Rooms Booked out--\n\n\n"
                + "Room No. " + room1to299
                + "Nightly Rate $" + obj.getRate());
        return obj;
    }
```

This is the HotelRoom class

```
public class HotelRoom 
{
    private int roomNo;
    private double rate;

    public HotelRoom(int roomNo, double rate) 
    {
        this.roomNo = roomNo;
        this.rate = rate;
        if(roomNo < 300)
            this.rate = 69.95;
        else
            this.rate = 89.95;
    }

    public int getRoomNo() 
    {
        return roomNo;
    }

    public void setRoomNo(int roomNo) 
    {
        this.roomNo = roomNo;
    }

    public double getRate() 
    {
        return rate;
    }

    public void setRate(double rate) 
    {
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() 
    {
        return "Room No.: " + roomNo + ", Rate: " + rate + '\n';
    } 


    public double increaseRate(double surcharge)
    {
        return (this.rate + surcharge);
    }
}
```

this is the class inheriting from HotelRoom

```
public class Suite extends HotelRoom
{
    private double surcharge = 40.00;

    public Suite(double surcharge, int roomNo, double rate) 
    {
        super(roomNo, rate);
        this.surcharge = surcharge;
    }

    public double getSurcharge() 
    {
        return surcharge;
    }

    public void setSurcharge(double surcharge) 
    {
        this.surcharge = surcharge;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() 
    {
        return super.toString() + "Surcharge: " + surcharge + 'n';
    }
}
```

This is the main method so far

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       ArrayList<HotelRoom> hrs = new ArrayList<>();
       int userSelect = menu();
       while(userSelect != 4)
       {
           switch(userSelect)
           {
               case 1:
                   subMenu();
                   break;
               case 2:
                   roomBooked();
                   break;
               case 3:
                   roomBookedAll();
                   break;
               default:
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input");
           }
       }


    }
    public static int menu()
    {
        String selectMenu = "--HOTEL RENTAL SYSTEM--\n\n"
                + "1. Choose a room type\n"
                + "2. Room rates information\n"
                + "3. Rooms currently booked\n\n"
                + "4. Exit";
        int select = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(selectMenu));
        return select;
    }
    public static void subMenu()
    {
        String subMenu = "1. Normal Hotel room\n"
                + "2. Suite\n\n"
                + "Choose room type";
        int select = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(subMenu)); 
        switch(select)
        {  
            case 1:
                roomNormal();
                break;
            case 2:
                roomSuite();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public static HotelRoom roomNormal()
    {
        int room1to299;
        double rate;
        HotelRoom obj = null;

        room1to299 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter room number"));
        rate = obj.getRate();
        obj = new HotelRoom(room1to299, rate);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"--Rooms Booked out--\n\n\n"
                + "Room No. " + room1to299
                + "Nightly Rate $" + obj.getRate());
        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: Cool. What's the problem?

Comment: obj requires a int, double. The double has a fixed value how do i pass that so that it can be stored into the arraylist

Comment: So the double is a constant? If so, make it a not constant.

Comment: I don't see an `ArrayList` anywhere in your code.

Comment: Can you show us the HotelRoom class entirely?

Comment: the value needs tor remain constant though

Comment: Yes, show us `HotelRoom` and also any/all classes it inherits from.  Hard to see where the problem which you describe as inheritance related when you don't even show us how you are inheriting the various values.

Comment: Ah I see, you want to pass a fixed rate. Why don't you just pass in the rate as in `rate = 2.5` instead of `rate = obj.getRate()` which throws an NPE.

Comment: I think he probably wants a static method (`HotelRoom.getRate()`) but it's hard to tell from his description.

Comment: Yeah, show us all of your code.

Comment: Well the `rate` you show in that class in NOT fixed, programmatically speaking.  Are you sure you're thinking about this right? What about just making a global `public final static double ROOM_RATE = 42.0;`

Comment: I guess different rooms can have different rates, hence the inheritance.

Comment: You are passing in the rate in the constructor, but don't actually do anything with it since you overwrite it right away. You can just remove it.

Comment: My instructions are to use room and rate in a constructor that inherits a surcharge from another class

Comment: Okay, so just create a hotelroom, then add the hotelroom to the arrayList. So if you want to add it to the ArrayList, when you call it, just put `hrs.add(roomNormal());`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Change every `roomNormal();` to `hrs.add(roomNormal());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little vague, so I assume the error is in the first block of code you've provided, which is the roomNormal() method. That being said, your HotelRoom object `obj` needs to be initialized first before it can access the getRate() method. Otherwise, it will throw a null pointer exception.

Solution: `rate = 4.5` instead of `rate = obj.getRate()`

Comment: This worked as the constructor set value override the temp value, Thanks heaps, NickL also suggested which I overlooked and thanks to everyone for your assistance.